# How to bind a date for a dynamic query

Tags: sql, plsql

I'm developing a script that executes a dynamically build query with a check on a date in it.
This is not the actual scipt it's just a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), to show my problem:

```
DECLARE
  lv_query VARCHAR2(500);  
  lv_date  DATE;
BEGIN
  lv_date := &cutomDate;
  lv_query := 'select * from executionlog e
           where e.execution_timestamp > ' || lv_date;
  dbms_output.put_line(lv_query);
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE(lv_query);
END;
```

When I give a custom date for example: `to_date('01011987','ddmmyyyy')` I get the following string as my query :

> select * from executionlog e
>              where e.execution_timestamp > 01-JAN-87

I got the following error:

> ORA-00904 error: "JAN":invalid identifier.

I understand this query can't execute correctly, because e.execution_timestamp is a Date and 01-JAN-87 is a Varchar2.

How can I convert 01-JAN-87 back to a date? I allready played around with `to_date` but I cannot get the desired result so far.

I cannot change the fact that the query is dynamically build.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a bind variable instead of concatenating:

```
DECLARE
  lv_query VARCHAR2(500);
  lv_date  DATE;
BEGIN
  lv_date := &cutomDate;
  lv_query := 'select * from executionlog e
           where e.execution_timestamp > :pDate';
  dbms_output.put_line(lv_query);
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE lv_query USING lv_date;
END;
```

Rather than have the user use the TO_DATE function, you could prompt for a string and TO_DATE it in the code:

```
DECLARE
  lv_query VARCHAR2(500);
  lv_date  DATE;
BEGIN
  lv_date := TO_DATE(&cutomDate,'DDMMYYYY');
  lv_query := 'select * from executionlog e
           where e.execution_timestamp > :pDate';
  dbms_output.put_line(lv_query);
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE lv_query USING lv_date;
END;
```

So now the user just types `01011987` when prompted.

Comment: Good idea to prompt for a string! Your solution works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar situation.  The difference is that I was on sql server connecting to oracle with openquery.  That meant that I had to send an sql string to oracle, similar to what you are doing.  I found that the format:

```
{ts 'yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss'}
```

would give good results.  I wrote a function that returned this:

```
select @StringOut = '{ts ''''' + convert(varchar(20), @DateIn, 20) + ''''' }';
```

In your case, you'll have to use to_char with the appropriate mask.  The hard part will probably be getting the correct number of single quotes.